# Why does OpenVPN enable routes I don't want?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I am trying to set up a VPN connection to an OpenVPN server, but without any default routes, so I can configure those myself. Basically what I'm looking for is a mostly unchanged system (all routing as before), but with the interface `tun0` present so an application can connect to it.

The configuration file I'm starting with looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote de-fra.mullvad.net 1194

cipher AES-256-CBC
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
remote-cert-tls server
ping 10
ping-restart 60
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288

fast-io

auth-user-pass mullvad_userpass.txt
ca mullvad_ca.crt

tun-ipv6
script-security 2

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA
```

It is adapted from the default Mullvad configuration file, with the calls to `update-resolv-conf.sh` removed (the rationale being that this is not mentioned in most OpenVPN guides and I want as little interference with my system as possible).

```
ec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: /sbin/ip -6 addr add fdda:d0d0:cafe:1194::1000/64 dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: add_route_ipv6(::/2 -> fdda:d0d0:cafe:1194:: metric -1) dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: /sbin/ip -6 route add ::/2 dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: add_route_ipv6(4000::/2 -> fdda:d0d0:cafe:1194:: metric -1) dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: /sbin/ip -6 route add 4000::/2 dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: add_route_ipv6(8000::/2 -> fdda:d0d0:cafe:1194:: metric -1) dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: /sbin/ip -6 route add 8000::/2 dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: add_route_ipv6(c000::/2 -> fdda:d0d0:cafe:1194:: metric -1) dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: /sbin/ip -6 route add c000::/2 dev tun0
Dec 25 11:52:39 Hurler ovpn-mullvad_de-fra[8378]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Where do these routes come from?

Comment: Just an FYI, your config is an inefficient bottleneck for throughput.  There is no legitimate reason to use anything greater than AES128 for the SSL & TLS ciphers, as AES128 will remain uncrackable for at least a decade, if not longer; If you're super paranoid about the security of the data, lower the `rekey` values.  There's also no HMAC authentication (`auth sha256` for x86, `auth sha512` for x64), of which prevents MITM attacks.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently just using the configuration Mullvad gave me.

Comment: Just an FYI: There's no point in running encryption higher than AES128, as it will remain uncrackable through 2030 at the minimum... all you're doing is massively slowing throughput to a crawl with AES256.  Mullvad is either not using OpenVPN 2.4, which was released ~4yrs ago, of which enabled the usage of the vastly more efficient TLS EC ciphers, or they've improperly configured the client config, as AFAIK, `tls-cipher` must be specified in the server config, not client config.  I'm also not sure why they're using a SHA384 cipher suite, as it's not in common use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN servers can push settings such as routes to clients.

You can theoretically filter which wille be accepted by your client using [pull filters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337675/319687), however this was not what worked in my case.

I needed the directive [`route-nopull`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16500/how-to-refuse-routes-that-are-pushed-by-openvpn-server/337675#comment461671_17311).

Answer (score 1):

Answering the *why* of "Where do these routes come from?"

Looking at the routes:

```
0000::/2
4000::/2
8000::/2
c000::/2
```

Those four /2 subnets represent the *whole* IPv6 Internet. That's a (bit hacky) way to override the default route (which would be ::/0) without deleting it. Many OpenVPN configurations do the same for IPv4, by adding those routes:

```
0.0.0.0/1
128.0.0.0/1
```

This allows to still have precedence over 0.0.0.0/0 (or ::/0) if the default route metric were also the lowest possible: 0.

This link gives ways to prevent this on the client side:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway